# Elastic Search: Boosting results

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, elastica

I have many objects that have been indexed in ES. Two of each object's properties is "type" and "title". Is there any way to boost results so that if a certain type in the result set is the majority, the title is weighs much more than the other properties such as "description"?

Edit: I am already boosting certain properties. But I want, given a certain characteristic of the result set(most types are the similar), to further boost another field.

Comment: I think you may be able to with some custom scoring. Can you please give an example of the query, and then 2 results which are returned where you want the order to be reversed to what it is currently?

Answer (score 0):

you can add boosting to your query:

for example:

```
"term": {
        "terms": {
          "value": "stranger then fiction",
          "boost": 1.8
        }
```

read more here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/boost-field/

Comment: The link doesn't relate to your example. You can always boost a specific query through the `boost` field, while the boosting query is a specific query.